# .stop().animate({ left:"-100%" }, 500, function()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get a set of divs to slide from right to left - for the next - and left to right - for last (previous). This is a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8cjgswL8/125/

Initial state of all divs is done via css - below;

```
.pane
{
width: 80%;
height: 60%;

display: inline-block;

position: absolute;
top: 10%; left: 100%;

color:black;
background: #A9F5A9;
}
```

The next div is gotten with this javascript - and works fine;

```
$(THIS_PAGE).stop().animate({
               left:"-100%"
        }, 500, function(){            
        });

        $(NEXT_PAGE).stop().animate({
            left:"10%"
            }, 500);
```

And the last uses this;

```
$(THIS_PAGE).stop().animate({
            left:"-100%"
        }, 500, function(){         
        }); 

        $(LAST_PAGE).stop().animate({
            left:"10%"
        }, 500);
```

This sort of works by getting the right divs into the right place, but what I'm trying to achieve is for next divs to come from the right to the left (and the current one to exit to the left) and for the last one to come in from the right (and the current one to exit to the right).

At the moment, when the 'last' one comes in, the 'current' one still seems to exit left.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: most sliders are done by wrapping all the children in a wrapper and then moving that left or right by the width of the slides, would give you the effect you are after (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the minus sign when animating THIS_PAGE left when last button is clicked.

```
$(THIS_PAGE).stop().animate({
            left:"100%"
        }, 500, function(){         
        }); 

        $(LAST_PAGE).stop().animate({
            left:"10%"
        }, 500);
```

Comment: That works a treat - thank you very much. I thought I'd tried all combinations, but was probably losing my sense of where things were.

Comment: Thanks very much. This works a treat. I tried all sorts of combinations to no effect.

Comment: Sometimes you just need to sleep on it :) I would appreciate it if you could mark this as the accepted answer, thanks.

Comment: Hi, this is the accepted answer - many thanks. I thought there was a button for this, but can't seem to see it. PhilB